# In clauses with sql interpolation

Tags: scala, scalikejdbc

Can I use in-clauses with ScalikeJDBC's SQL Interpolation? e.g.

```
val ids = Set(1,2,3,5)
sql"""update foo set bar=${bar} where id in ${ids}""".update().apply()
```

This fails because `ids` is not interpolated.

```
sql"""update foo set bar=${bar} where id in (${ids.mkString(",")})""".update().apply()
```

This also fails because the expression is intepreted as a String, not a list of numbers. e.g. `... where id in ('1,2,3,5')`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've not figured out your issue, but interpolating Set value should work.

```
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.scalikejdbc" %% "scalikejdbc"       % "2.2.6",
  "com.h2database"  %  "h2"                % "1.4.187",
  "ch.qos.logback"  %  "logback-classic"   % "1.1.3"
)
```

like this:

```
scala> import scalikejdbc._
import scalikejdbc._

scala> val ids = Set(1,2,3,5)
ids: scala.collection.immutable.Set[Int] = Set(1, 2, 3, 5)

scala> val s = sql"""update foo set bar=1 where id in (${ids})"""
s: scalikejdbc.SQL[Nothing,scalikejdbc.NoExtractor] = scalikejdbc.SQLToTraversableImpl@633229c7

scala> s.statement
res1: String = update foo set bar=1 where id in (?, ?, ?, ?)

scala> s.parameters
res2: Seq[Any] = List(1, 2, 3, 5)
```

Comment: You are quite correct. I don't know what I was doing wrong before. I've rolled back to what I thought I tried initially and it's working now. ありがとう

Comment: Not sure if was the cause the OP's problem, but if you accidentally use Java collections, you silently get aberrant interpolation behaviour: `scala> sql"""update foo set bar=1 where id in (${Set(5, 1, 2, 3, 4).asJava})""".statement` gives
`res2: String = update foo set bar=1 where id in (?)`. This caused some problems for me; I might file a bug against scalikejdbc.

Comment: I filed a [ScalikeJDBC bug](https://github.com/scalikejdbc/scalikejdbc/issues/469).